# MPAndroidChart PieChart Angles

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I needed a pie chart with three entries in the data set so that when i touch the chart it rotates to the correct data( This means it starts at data[0] -> click -> spin to data[1] -> click -> spin to data[2] -> click -> spin to data[0]).

The solution I've implemented goes something like this :

```
START_OFFSET = 95;
_index0= absoluteAngles[0] - (drawAngles[0] / 2) - START_OFFSET ;
_index1= absoluteAngles[1] - (drawAngles[1] / 2) - START_OFFSET ;
_pendingPieOffset = absoluteAngles[2] - (drawAngles[2] / 2) - START_OFFSET;
```

And here are where the problems start. This supposedly gives me the correct angle as in `absoluteAngle` represents the end of the slice and `drawAngles` represents the width of the slice. So even though my math is correct I can't center the center of each slice with the bottom.

```
      _overlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
    ...
case AVAILABLE_BALANCE:
    _pieChart.spin(SPIN_DURATION, _index2, _index0, Easing.EasingOption.EaseInCubic);
    break;
case USED_BALANCE:
   _pieChart.spin(SPIN_DURATION, _index0, _index1, Easing.EasingOption.EaseInCubic);
   break;
case PENDING_BALANCE:
   _pieChart.spin(SPIN_DURATION, _index1, _index0, Easing.EasingOption.EaseInCubic);
    break;
    ....
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did some similar functionality in my project, maybe it will help you:

```
@Override
public void onValueSelected(Entry e, int dataSetIndex, Highlight h) {
    //get current angle
    float start = chart.getRotationAngle();
    //get index of current slice
    int i = e.getXIndex();
    //calculate center of slice 
    float offset = mDrawAngles[i] / 2;
    // calculate the next angle
    float end = 270f-(mAbsoluteAngles[i]-offset);

    //rotate to slice center
    chart.spin(SPIN_DURATION,start,end,Easing.EasingOption.EaseInOutQuad);
}
```

Just implement **OnChartValueSelectedListener** interface in activity or fragment - [MPAndroidChart Wiki](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Interaction-with-the-Chart/).

P.S. In my case, selected slice is centered at the top.(Change 270 to 90 for bottom)